# Select the "back" button of the Firefox browser to right click and Select the Option from the right click Menu in Selenium Web Driver - Java

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium webdriver . I want to select the "back " button of the firefox and right click the back button and select an option.

I see there is  "Actions" API to right click, But i am not able to select/find  the "back" button element  of the firefox to right click using selenium .

Can any one please help me .

Code iam trying is ::  Using firefox Driver to inittate the Webdriver

```
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
    action.contextClick(productLink).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

In the above code , in place of "productlink", i should select the back button element of the firefox browser  to right click .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with Selenium.

You can use AutoIT with Selenium to click on that.
Refer to the following article on how to use AutoIT.
http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: @user200290 If your intent is only to **Navigate back** then you may want to make use of  `driver.navigate().back();` but if you desire to right click on back button and select one of the options, you'll need to implement 3rd party utilities/tools like AutoIT

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do. Try to use "Navigation" Commands in selenium.

driver.navigate().to("http://www.DemoQA.com");

there are many commands you can perform on it. If you still find issues using it let me know.